# Linear first order ODE with exponential coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I have a problem. I have to solve a linear first order, homogeneous ODE with an exponential coefficient.The equation is as follows; 
$\frac{dP(x)}{dt}-e^{-ax}P(x)=0$. 
Clearly, its impossible to find an IF here, because that would result in an exponential of an exponential.Are there any alternate methods to handle? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it correct that the differentiation is done with respect to $t$ and not to $x$? If so, then $x = x(t)$, isn't it?

Comment: So sorry. Derivative is with respect to x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dP}{dx}-e^{ax} P=0 \implies \int \frac{dp}{P}=\int e^{ax} dx \implies \log P= \frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C \implies P(x)=C_1 e^{\frac{e^{ax}}{a}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Now you may accept one answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential of exponential do not make a problem. If you prefer, let $P(x)=e^{Q(x)}$
$$\frac{dP(x)}{dx}=e^{-ax}P(x)\implies \frac{dQ(x)}{dx}=e^{-ax}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.